# How do I open and extract data from this .dat.gz file in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, gzip, readfile, astronomy

I am trying to extract data from this file:

[https://slac.stanford.edu/~behroozi/BPlanck_Trees/tree_0_0_0.dat.gz](https://slac.stanford.edu/%7Ebehroozi/BPlanck_Trees/tree_0_0_0.dat.gz)

It is a .dat.gz file. I downloaded it through my terminal and de-compressed it so that it is a .dat file. However when I run:

```py
f = open('tree_0_0_0.dat', 'r')
data = np.genfromtxt(f)
```

I get:

```py
array([],dtype=float64)
```

Why is it an empty array. How do I extract the data in here? Did I maybe de-compress it incorrectly?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should simply look at the first 100 lines of your .dat file and see if it is what you are expecting. What is the size of your .dat file?

Line 47 of that file has a single number, which then leads numpy to expect one element per row thereafter when there are really 57 elements per row. I commented out line 47 by putting a "#" in front of the number. Then `np.genfromtxt` worked on a truncated example.

I say "truncated", because the entire file is ginormous. I just pulled the first 1000 lines to try importing. Are you sure you want to read all 23 million rows into memory? It will take on the order of 10 GB in a numpy array. How much RAM does your machine have?

You may want to think about how to process this data serially, as opposed to reading the whole thing in at once.